# prevent any sabotage while upload file in php

Tags: php, security, file-upload

As you know there are a simple normal way to upload file in php .
for security check I just check    `type` of file and its `size` , but is it enough ? If the answer is NO , what should I do to prevent any sabotage?
for exaple is it enough  :

```
<form action="php-ajax-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload-target" onsubmit="upload_start();">
<label for="user-file"></label>
<input type="file" id="user-file" name="user-file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

php :

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["user-file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" && $_FILES["user-file"]["size"] < 1000000) {
    if ($_FILES["user-file"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "<div class=\"server\">error: " . $_FILES["user-file"]["error"] . "</div><br />";
        $check_result = 0;
        }
    else{
        if (file_exists("user-upload/" . $_FILES["user-file"]["name"])){
            echo "<div class=\"server\">this file exists <br /><br />".$_FILES["user-file"]["name"]. "</div><br />";
            $check_result = 0;      
            }
        else{         
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["user-file"]["tmp_name"],"user-upload/" . $_FILES["user-file"]["name"]);
            echo "file: " . $_FILES["user-file"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "type: " . $_FILES["user-file"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "size: " . ($_FILES["user-file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
            echo "directory : " . "user-upload/" . $_FILES["user-file"]["name"]. "<br />";
            $check_result = 1;      
            }
    }
}
else{
    if($_FILES["user-file"]["size"] > 1000000){
        echo "<div class=\"server\">too large </div>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<div class=\"server\">format error</div>";
    }
    $check_result = 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: dunno what you mean, but what about checksum? easy to calculate befor & after uploading and compare.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to check the type, so the end user will not upload malicious PHP files. Also, you can protect yourself against flooding, for instance, I can write a program which will visit your site and upload images again and again and again, until your hard drive is filled. You might want to track the IP addresses and detect flood attempts. Also, you might add captcha to your form to prevent flooding. You need to make sure you do not allow apostrophes and stuff like that in the file names, as they could be part of an injection attack.